# Google Maps V3 Route Destination Mark Edit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using the google.maps.DirectionsService.route() and google.maps.DirectionsRenderer.setDirections() method, is it possible to change the text on the info window for the destination, without creating a custom parser for the journey?

I couldn't see anything in the API which allowed you to access the markers of the route.

I don't want any code, just yes/no, and a hint for the right direction to take.

Current Function:

```
   var request = {
        origin: origPoint, 
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(dest.lat(), dest.lng()),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        region: "GB"
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Psy

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the api doesn't offer a direct way to access the info windows or access the markers.

But there are several ways to achieve that parsing parts of the result data:

1. I guess the simplest way to change text on the info window is to overwrite the DirectionsLegs' start and/or end addresses of the DirectionsResult. You have to do it before calling `directionsDisplay.setDirections(result)`.
2. Or you can display just the polyline (see suppressMarkers and suppressInfoWindows of renderer's options) and create the markers and infowindows yourself - you have to access data from DirectionsLegs of DirectionsResult.

I would prefer the second way since it's cleaner and you have more freedom in adjustments. The first way, it's only a hack and you are just changing the text.